# AWS S3 ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 63

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

When I am attempting to pull the content of the files into a CSV file, I get this error: ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 63. The strange thing is that this error was not occurring before, i.e. I didn't not touch this code and 1 day it was working and the next it wasn't. This inconsistent behavior is the issue and I am not sure what to do.

I hope someone knows that the issue is.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have some bad data in column 63 with your latest batch of data. What's in column 63?

Comment: @ee8291 the data never changed but the error did. As I mentioned this code worked yesterday and today I reran and it’s giving me this error. I checked that column and see some missing values, however there are even columns before column 63 , ie column 12,17, etc. which show the same missing value pattern but for these, no error occurred. Thus, this is very strange behavior. Is there anything in the code I can modify?

Comment: Actually, I am experiencing a similar issue. Except I am just trying to get the file and not parse it as a CSV. I get a `ValueError` and with no message on the exception.